# Cassandra Lucene index for search in map type

Tags: database, cassandra, lucene, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We've met the task to develop an extensible schema for different sets of parameters with an ability to search within them by also combining multipe criteria values. We solved that task by using Map type and built Stratio Lucene index upon that map.
Here is our scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE logging_events (
  event_id              UUID,
  event_parameters   MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
);
```

And here is lucene index:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX logging_events_index ON logging_events()
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
    'schema': '{
      fields: {
        "event_parameters": {type: "string"},
      }
    }'};
```

We used that approach cause for different events we have different set of parameters.

Now my question is how reliable are that things and what possible problems we can meet in production. Is that approach good or bad for our case? Thx a lot for ur answers.

And we understand that without index we wont be able to search at all even with filtering.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of tests and running this architecture under load during a month it seems a valid case. And due to Cassandra's nosql nature it seems that this is one the main Cassandra's features due to weak data schema. Advantages of this approach is that u wont have to rebuild the index after schema update or smth like that. But be ready for serious space consumption