# With Cassandra, How can I achieve order by any columns or any key in a map?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-lucene-index

I want to store any key value in DB and display the data with sort and filter.
What should I do with cassandra to support this?

I understand Cassandra is very stable and scalable.

I know that cassandra can only sort by clustering keys.
But I do need the sorting on any column and I dont want to copy data around.

I am really curious about how people do this with Cassandra.

Or Cassandra users never do those kind of things?

And finally, I want to store customized key,value pairs in DB and also be able to query the key with sort and filter. Should I use Cassandra with Spark to support all those features? Or Can I use Cassandra-Lucene plugin to support sort by any column? any drawback it will bring?

Appreciate your comment!

Comment: I think it'd be better for you take [this quick and impactful data modeling by example free browser-based course](https://www.datastax.com/learn/data-modeling-by-example) to get a deeper understand of how data modeling works in C*. Also, providing a sample schema and data example of what do you refer as _customized key/value pairs_ may be beneficial to triage this effectively.

Comment: @Madhavan Thank you! For "sorting/query on non-primary key", do you think I should use Lucene index plugin of Cassandra?

Comment: you would need to explore SAI to see if it would fit your bill here, https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/developing/cql/indexing/sai/sai-overview.html

Comment: @Madhavan Appreciate your comment here! I will check that out. Looks like SAI cannot support order by any key of a map column. Order by any key of a map column is my major concern.

Comment: Your original questions asked about non-primary column sorting and now you're referring to keys of map. Please update your original questions with elaborate details (with schema, complete query you want to run and may be some example rows) on what you want to achieve and folks can chime in to triage this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that Cassandra Lucence plugin can help on sorting by any  column. Especially, it can sort by any key in a map. So that I can store <key,value> pair in map and sort/search by the key in the map.
I am not sure whether this is the preferred solution or there are any other better solution.
[Cassandra Lucene index for search in map type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155297/cassandra-lucene-index-for-search-in-map-type)